# Changing the geometry of polygon in OpenLayers 2

Tags: openlayers-2

I would like to programmatically change the geometry of a polygon. `feature.geometry.move()` works OK, but I rather need supply a whole new geometry. When I try `feature.geometry = newGeometry`, the feature duplicates itself, rather then changes its position. I read the relevant code in OpenLayers and I can't see why is this happening. Any help welcomed.

```
function init(){
    var map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');
    map.addLayer(new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("Mapnik"));
    map.setCenter(fromLL(new OpenLayers.LonLat(14.302,50.093561)), 14);    


    //vector layer
    var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("");
    map.addLayer(layer);

    //one feature
    var geometry = fromLL(OpenLayers.Bounds.fromString("14.2989,50.0935,14.3018,50.0965")).toGeometry();
    var rectangle = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(geometry);
    layer.addFeatures(rectangle);

    //move it 30pixels up - works
    rectangle.geometry.move(0,map.getResolution()*30);
    layer.redraw();

    //change geometry - wrong - duplicates
    rectangle.geometry = fromLL(OpenLayers.Bounds.fromString("14.302,50.0935,14.6018,50.0965")).toGeometry();
    rectangle.geometry.clearBounds();
    layer.redraw();
}

function toLL(obj){return obj.transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"), new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"));}
function fromLL(obj){return obj.transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"));}
```

Comment: Soemthing to try first is to set the name of your vector layer - var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("MyLayer");

Comment: Also try layer.drawFeature(rectangle); after you've changed the geometry

Comment: drawFeature(rectangle) and redraw() acts the same, nameing the layer also didnt help. But thanks for ideas

Answer (score 4):

Destroying the features then adding the new ones to the layers should work:

```
...
    //move it 30pixels up - works
    rectangle.geometry.move(0, map.getResolution() * 30);
    layer.redraw();

    layer.destroyFeatures(rectangle);

    rectangle = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(fromLL(OpenLayers.Bounds.fromString("14.302,50.0935,14.6018,50.0965")).toGeometry());
    layer.addFeatures(rectangle);
...
```

**EDIT #1**

If you want to move the feature with the mouse you can use [OpenLayers.Control.DragFeature](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.10/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Control/DragFeature-js.html#OpenLayers.Control.DragFeature).

[Here's an example](http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/drag-feature.html)

Comment: Yes, thats works as expected. But ive considered it a bit untidy. Since i want to move this rectangle realtime by mouse, creating a new object on every mousemove doesnt seem right.

Comment: Ahh, then use OpenLayers.Control.DragFeature.... see my edit.

Comment: Thanks! that's what I needed. But as zbycz says, it feels untidy, but I have now choice with the way I do (drawing and animating a part of a pathway)